# Issue with ng-html-compile displaying UI-Grid twice while rendering saved HTML from SQL Server Database

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

1)I am saving entire DIV - TestDIV from a HTML page in AngularJS to SQLServer database.

2)TestDIV has many DIVs nested inside it, including UI-Grids.

3)I save the HTML as a VARCHAR(MAX) column in SQL Server. I am able to save and retrieve the HTML correctly.

4)On page - Test.HTML - I have a another DIV - with ID =  TestDIVDisplayed

5)I am assigning saved HTML to TestDIVDisplayed  using ng-html-compile. Basically setting ng-html-compile to HTMLBindValue

6)This seems to work, with an issue esp. with UI-Grid. The UI-Grid is displayed twice, instead of once. Something similar to the following -

[image]

7)The assignment is done the following way in JavaScript code -

```
 var toChg = 'TestDIVDisplayed';
                var btn = document.querySelector('#' + toChg);
                btn.setAttribute("ng-html-compile", "HTMLBindValue");
                var el = $(btn);
                $compile(el)($scope);
                $scope.mySidenav = entity.DivSavedInSQLServerDatabase; //Getting the entity.DivSavedInSQLServerDatabase from a WebAPI service call.
```

Comment: You should post the code so we can see how you are doing it instead of you trying to describe it.

Comment: Added code snippet with examples.